# Changing "*ngIf= 'condition | async as data' to [hidden]" in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have

```
 <div *ngIf='condition | async as data'>
    <div *ngIf='data.length > 0'>some html to render ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

which is removing the div element from DOM.
In my scenario I need div element to be always present in DOM.
So I was trying `<div [hidden]='!condition | async as data'>`
I found that async doesn't work with [hidden]

Answer (score 0):

when you has an "async" and you need "repeat", a tipical way is create "on fly" an object in a ng-container and ask about the object

```html
<!--see that the property is always true-->
<ng-container *ngIf="{data:condition|async} as obj">
  <!--see that you ask about obj.data-->
  <!--I use an unique *ngIf-->
  <div *ngIf="obj.data && obj.data.length">
           ..put your code...
           ..if data is an array you can iterate..
           ..eg.
      <div *ngFor="let item of obj.data">
           {{item.id}}
      </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting unexpected token 'as' and unexpected token obj

Comment: And one more thing i dont want *ngIf as that removes html element from DOM,
I want the html element to be present in DOM always so instead of *ngIf I am using [hidden]

Comment: @GodricGryffindor, I just make a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9vc3ey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html -condition is an observable -I create it using rxjs `of`  and work for me. About hidden use `<div [hidden]="!obj.data || obj.data.length<=0">`, really I like more `<div [style.display]="!obj.data || obj.data.length<=0?'none':null">`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your element (or style), and with this set the visibility to hidden:

Setting style directly:

```
<div [style.visibility]="((condition | async) as data) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"><div *ngIf='data?.length'>some html to render ...</div></div>`
```

Adding a class to set CSS through that:

```
    <div [class.hidden]="((condition | async) as data)"><div *ngIf='data?.length'>some html to render ...</div></div>`
```

(Have not tested using 'as' inside these bindings, but assume that will work - using the data/pipe itself I have tested before.